# AIR device movement along a singla plane

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

We are developing an app using air for android. The app requires movement of the device in a single plane. The user will hold the device and rotate in his position, keeping the device stationary with his/her respect. Since the device is held fixed in its axis, we cannot use the accelerometer. Is there any other way we can get any value corresponding to this movement using actionscript, i.e air for android?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If the user is rotating and keeping the device fixed with respect to himself, then the device's 'plane' is constantly changing. No? Instead of 'plane' do you mean 'plane within the frame of reference of the user'?  If so why not use the accelerometer for movements perpendicular to the rotational direction and just subtract out (or add by subtracting negatives) the movement components in the direction of the rotation?

Comment: Actually i have tried the accelerometer. The procedure is like taking a photo. The user will move the device in horizontal axis. I was able to extract the vertical movement. But while moving horizontally, none of the accelerometer readings provide any notable change.